# Refused to load the script 'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id=GTM-T44GGZR'

Tags: joomla, google-tag-manager

I pasted the googletag manager code in my joomla website, But it showing following error in console. and also not reflection in the google dashboard

Refused to load the script 'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id=GTM-T44GGZR' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' data: *.googleapis.com *.gstatic.com *.google-analytics.com *.youtube.com *.g.doubleclick.net https://s.ytimg.com/yts/jsbin/ *.googleadservices.com *.google.com *.google.cz http://platform.linkedin.com cdnjs.cloudflare.com static.hotjar.com widget.prodpad.com api-widget.prodpad.com vars.hotjar.com script.hotjar.com insights.hotjar.com wss://ws4.hotjar.com www.google.com.pk wss://ws1.hotjar.com wss://ws5.hotjar.com https://www.transguardgroup.com". Note that 'script-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.

Answer (score 3):

Google Tag Manager is a script injector (and actually it injects itself via a few lines of bootstrap code), so it will not work with `unsafe-inline` in place.

Simo Ahava has an article about [configuring your CSP for GTM](https://www.simoahava.com/analytics/google-tag-manager-content-security-policy/), but that basically removes the protection your CSP is supposed to offer, so you have to choose between the convenience of GTM or the security via a CSP.